# Mobiscroll Time change Validation Start and EndTime

Tags: mobiscroll

I need to do Validation for both Start Time And End Time, if start time is greater then end Time Throw and error.

How Can i achieve this.
Which Events do i need to use to get the validation done onselect, onclose??
Please Help me out

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the datetime preset? (please be a bit more specific...)

Comment: I am using Time Preset and yes when u do .Scroller('getDate') iam gettign the date Time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using onSelect event making changes to the mobiscroll.

Here is an example i tried.. you might find useful

```
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        var newMinDate, newMaxDate;
        endDate = new Date(dateText);
        var newEndDate = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), endDate.getDate() + 5);
        $endCal.mobiscroll('setDate', newEndDate);
        newMinDate = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), endDate.getDate() + 1),
        $endCal.mobiscroll('option', {
            minDate: newMinDate
        });
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sarvesh310/742Lqagk/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the minDate and maxDate options in the onSelect event, e.g.:

```
$('#end_time').scroller('option', 'minDate', $('#start_time').scroller('getDate'));
```

A working example (does not allow to select a start date > end date):

http://jsfiddle.net/dioslaska/2MVv6/1/

This works with date and datetimepickers as well.

Comment: Thanks, But that works only if you have a predefined start time what if I don't have any start tim??